# multiple out of office reply in outlook365

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I make multiple out of office reply in outlook 365?
example: I want to make automatic reply during lunch (with a specific time) and automatic reply during weekends without setting up again and again.

Comment: [Recurring out of office?](//superuser.com/q/1119086)

Comment: Even if you can’t set up such a multiple-range configuration, you might be able to write a VBA routine that will handle the repetitive day-by-day setup.   It’s been years since I’ve used Outlook, so I can’t help you with any details, but maybe somebody else will be able to take this idea and run with it (or say that it can’t possibly work).